# how can I rewrite this ObjC method "rightButtons" in swift

Tags: swift

I want to rewrite the object-c code below to swift

```
- (NSArray *)rightButtons
{
    NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
     [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0]
                                            title:@"More"];
    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
     [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f]
                                            title:@"Delete"];

    return rightUtilityButtons;
}
```

sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor is defined below:

```
#import "NSMutableArray+SWUtilityButtons.h"

@implementation NSMutableArray (SWUtilityButtons)

- (void)sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:(UIColor *)color title:(NSString *)title
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.backgroundColor = color;
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button.titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [self addObject:button];
}
```

especially the header file name has a "+" mark, how can I initialize a instance of  "NSMutableArray+SWUtilityButtons.h"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough. Add an extension in Swift like this

```
extension NSMutableArray
{

func sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor(color : UIColor, title : String)
    {
        var button:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        button.backgroundColor = color;
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
        button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth;
        self.addObject(button)
    }
}
```

Extensions can be accessed from anywhere in your project. You don't need to import like you did with categories in Objective-C. So just use like this

```
var rightUtilityButtons : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
rightUtilityButtons.sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor(UIColor.redColor(), title: "More")
```